# what is the reason of using different version of sqlite in android?

Tags: android

what is the reason of using different version of sqlite in android ? and please tell me difference between all version and in which circumtances we can use different version of sqlite in android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably do not need to worry and stick to the highest version available today.

The versioning mechanism is here to avoid future problems if sqlite releases a new version with an incompatible api.

Making sure you declare the version you need will make your application more future-proof.

Comment: thanks for your reply....so,if i use sqlite version 3.0 then it will compatible for all android versions and all features of android??

Comment: Yes android Will continue to ship 3.0 and your application Will keep working. Maybe not for 20 years if they stop shipping it at some point when sqlite will have released several versions but you are pretty safe using 3.0.